# Trying to fix warning in clojure version of jclouds: "WARNING: failed to find key for value ... choosing first:"

Tags: java, clojure, jclouds, clojure-java-interop

I'm using [org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-all "1.9.2"] to connect to rackspace's cloudfiles. I'm able to connect, upload, download, etc but everytime I do I get the following warning

```
org.jclouds.logging.jdk.JDKLogger logWarn
WARNING: failed to find key for value https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/ in {ORD=https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_b7d2079b-f944-4ed3-8b0a-ae9360a53531, SYD=https://storage101.syd2.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_b7d2079b-f944-4ed3-8b0a-ae9360a53531, IAD=https://storage101.iad3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_b7d2079b-f944-4ed3-8b0a-ae9360a53531, HKG=https://storage101.hkg1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_b7d2079b-f944-4ed3-8b0a-ae9360a53531, DFW=https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_b7d2079b-f944-4ed3-8b0a-ae9360a53531}; choosing first: ORD
```

From reviewing jclouds.blobstore source code, the url value is the default value in the jclouds rackspace-cloudfiles-us configuration. I also see methods for setting regions in java itself. I do not see any direct way in clojure to set these values. If I need to pick another region, I am apparently unable to directly do so in the clojure implementation.

Has anyone else attacked this? Any suggestions on how best to proceed in clojure or do I need to use java interop to do this? Thanks.

Here is the code that uploads the file

```
(defn upload-file!
  [file]
  (let [file_id  (str (uuid/v1))
        file_bytes (file-to-byte-array file)
        mimetype (mime-type-of file_bytes)
        the-blobstore (blobstore "rackspace-cloudfiles-us" "username" "value")
        the-blob-id (put-blob the-blobstore "container-name"
                     (blob file_id :payload file_bytes :content-type mimetype))]
    [file_id the-blob-id mimetype]))
```

Comment: Could you please include code samples where you call the API?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Added. Thanks for looking at the question.

Comment: The jclouds Clojure bindings have fallen into disrepair after many years of neglect.  You need to get at a RegionScopedBlobStoreContext which you cannot create directly from Clojure.